# Jenkins multibranch pipeline is unable to detect a branch from github

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using multibranch pipeline for my github repo which polls the github repo for changes but it is unable to identify a branch. I have tried manually scanning the repo as well(using Scan Repository Now). When I checked the log of repository scan found that it is skipping the branch without any reason/error.

Repository Scan Log: See branch - PH055018

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
[Tue Sep 18 01:48:11 CDT 2018] Starting branch indexing...
01:48:12 Connecting to https://github.***.com/api/v3 using admin/****** (GitHub Enterprise)
01:48:12 Connecting to https://github.***.com/api/v3 using admin/****** (GitHub Enterprise)
Examining Org/Branch1

  Checking branches...

  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch AO055200

  Getting remote pull requests...
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: AO055200 (still at 4591b6532f66cb042f577a010b15920d88228be4)

    Checking branch CR017933
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: CR017933 (still at 3adf73afbdac409122f8094bb613dfaf2e5ccf20)

    Checking branch PH055018

    Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: master (still at 76ffdb47caf9a544b1b19b4eb35d5b2df5fab77b)

  4 branches were processed

  Checking pull-requests...

    Checking pull request #29
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: PR-29 (still at aca8973b0b496292c1342dbf63bab25fec0f068e+76ffdb47caf9a544b1b19b4eb35d5b2df5fab77b)

  1 pull requests were processed

Finished examining Org/Branch1

[Tue Sep 18 01:48:15 CDT 2018] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 3.6 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Jenkins has identified only 3 out of 4 branches even though all 4 branches have the JenkinsFile.
Could anyone tell how do I debug this scenario?

Comment: Provide your jenkins file, it may have some error

Comment: I see that one of the four branches is a PR. Could it be that you do not see this one? It’ll be on the PR tab.

Comment: @JoergS this branch is indeed part of the PR and I see it in the PR tab. However, my point is, irrespective of PRs, jenkins should be able to identify the branches. Also, there are checks added for branches and PRs. In this case, branch check failed and PR check passed.

Comment: In the options for your multibranch project in the configuration for your github branch source you can configure Jenkins not to exclude PRs from the list of branches. Is it that what you were searching for? By default pull requests get excluded.